# Count items that match multiple requirements

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of items in a long list (dynamic range, the number of data changes every month) whose value in column B and C meet certain requirements.

[image]

I need to get how many chequing accounts are open, how many are closed etc.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim a as Integer
Dim b as Long

set b = Application.CountA(Column(1))

i = 1

a = 0

For Each Item in ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Cells(Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cells(i,"B").Value = "Open" And Cells(i,"C").Value = "Chequing" Then
        a = a + 1
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > b Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Range("H2").Value = a
```

Comment: In H3: `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$G3,$C:$C,H$2)` copy over and down the grid.

Comment: Also, your code is failing because you only increment `i` if the `If` statement evaluates to `True`. So `i` is always 1 more than `a`.

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless, I see. So I should put i=i+1 after end if. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You should get the last row of columns B and C, then iterate through the rows of column B to check if the value of the two ticks matches open and checked so you increment your counter. and in the loop when i> lastRowsC, it means the cell in column C is empty, so exit the loop.

```
lastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
nbOpenAndChequing = 0
For i = 1 To lastRowB
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = "Open" And Cells(i, "C").Value = "Chequing" Then
        nbOpenAndChequing = nbOpenAndChequing + 1
    End If
    If i > lastRowC Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Range("H2").Value = nbOpenAndChequing
```

Comment: Please let's avoid "code dump" answers, answers that are nothing more than a proposed code solution without explanation. While this *may* help the original poster, without text that gives a decent explanation of the original poster's problem and how your answer proposes to solve it, the answer cannot possibly help future visitors with similar problems, which is the entire purpose of this site.

Comment: I updated my answer, it should be better.